# java code changes while migrating from myisam to innoDB

Tags: java, jdbc, innodb, myisam

I want to migrate from Myisam to InnoDB.
I am using Plain JDBC to access database.

Do I need to change any Java code, queries or join syntax while doing this.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to change anything in your Java code..

you just need to change database engines in your tables in mysql server